# my javascript function only recognizes the first value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, function

i need help. I ve the following code at hand:

```js
// App.jsx
const { mutate: mutateSubtituloModal, data: dataSubtituloModal } = 
  useMutation({ //linha qualidade
  mutationKey: ['mutationSubtituloModal'],
  mutationFn: reqSubtituloModal,
  //retry:  true
})

function executaDados(){
    if(linhaQualidade > 0 && periodo >= 0){
        if(linhaProducao > 0){
            mutateSubtitiuloModal(linhaProducao, linhaQualidade, periodo);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
//req.jsx
export async function reqSubtituloModal(idLinhaProducao, idLinhaQualidade, periodo){
    console.log('producao: ' + idLinhaProducao, 'qualidade: ' + idLinhaQualidade, 'periodo: ' + periodo)
    const res = await Api.get(`/consulta/tv/${idLinhaProducao}/${idLinhaQualidade}/${periodo}`); //qualidade - escolha
    return res.data;
}
```

Dont find the name of variables and functions strange, my native language is different. But the fact is that the reqSubtituloModal function only recognizes the first value, that is, idLinhaProducao because it is only this value that is returning in the console, the others appear as undefined and I dont know why the funcition does not recognize the others. Within the second if(), before sending the data to the reqSubtituloModal function, I put a console to prove it and indeed, my variables have data but they dont show up in the console. I tried to do it this way too:

```js
function executaDados(){
    if(linhaQualidade > 0 && periodo >= 0){
        if(linhaProducao > 0){
            reqSubtituloModal(linhaProducao, linhaQualidade, periodo);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of passing the data to the mutation, I passed it directly to the function reqSubtituloModal and it worked, however, this way I don't receive anything in res.data. Can someone help me?

note from editor:
original code srcs:
[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqCIj.png)
[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x9y1.png)